# HTML5 canvas draws two rects instead of one

Tags: javascript, android, html, animation

Hi I have a problem with JQuery Mobile 1.1.1, Phonegap 2.0 on Android 4.1.
I want to draw a rect on the canvas with JS and HTML5.

Thats my HTML5 Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>App</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
<div data-role="page" id="dataPageBattery" data-theme="a">
    <h2 align="center">Battery State</h2>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Car Data</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" align="center">
        <canvas id="myBatteryCanvas" width="device-width" height="device-height">                        
            Sorry, your browser doesn't support canvas technology        
        </canvas>

    </div>
        <h4 align="center" id="batteryProzent"></h4>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="battery.js"></script>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="persFooter">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Connect</a></li>
                <li><a href="carView.html" data-icon="gear">Vehicles</a></li>
                <li><a href="infoView.html" data-icon="info">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>                                       
    $('#dataPageBattery').on('swipeleft',function(){ 
    $.mobile.changePage("geolocation.html", { transition: "slide"});    
    console.log('slideLeft');
    })  

    $('#dataPageBattery').on('swiperight',function(){ 
    $.mobile.changePage("fuelGauge.html", { transition: "slide", reverse: 'true'}); 
    console.log('slideLeft');
    })  
</script>
</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I load the Java Script file, after the content div. 
The JS file looks like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myBatteryCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var x = 50;
var y = HEIGHT - 30;
var mx = 2;
var my = 1;
var prozent = 1;

context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

function initBatt() {
x = 50;
y = HEIGHT - 30;
mx = 2;
my = 1;
prozent = 1;

context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
context.rect(122, 40, 54, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'floralwhite';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 4;
context.strokeStyle = '#303030';
context.stroke();

}

 initBatt();
 //$(document).on("pageshow", initBatt);
```

Problem: If I use the last line to start the function, I'll get two rects on the canvas after the second time I load this page. The first time, there is one rect, thats okay. The secon time, there are two. On with the right coordinates and another on the right behind my rect. But Why?

If I use the initBatt(); statement instead, there is no problems at all.
With both lines no problem with FF or IE9, only on Android 4.1!

Ideas?

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile caches pages so it's probably calling your `initBatt()` function  on a cached page causing it to draw the rectangle again, or something along those lines anyway.

Comment: How can I prevent the JQuery Mobile caching? It looks like this, because there is nothing called twice.

Comment: When you refresh, `initBatt()` is called again, making it twice.

Comment: with other coordinates? I can't refresh I'm using Phonegap on Android. I swipe between two pages! How can I prevent the second calling? UPDATE: I put a flag inside initBatt() to control, if it's called twice. It isn't! Still the same problem.

Comment: Read up on jQuery Mobile's events (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html) to see when initBatt() should be called.

Comment: I use the .on() method to do this with the event pageshow! Whats wrong with that?

Comment: The pageshow event gets called every time the page is "shown" (hence the name) and this is why your initBatt() function is being called again. Perhaps try calling it on pageload? Failing that, read the docs to try and find out which event is the best one to call it on.

Comment: And this problem only happens with Phonegap and Android and not with Firefox oder IE?? Thats too strange to be true;

Comment: Besides: I don't want to load it only once! I want to load it every time I see the page, because later I want to do a little animation. And it should work every time.